# c++20 std::integral_constant?

Tags: c++, std

I'm just into metaprogramming and was watching Cppcon channel on youtube, and saw this [`std::integral_constant`](https://youtu.be/tiAVWcjIF6o?list=PLHTh1InhhwT6VxYHtoWIvOup9gz0p95Qr&t=1515), but cannot find its use.

As far as i understood, it is a way to "pack" a value along with its type, it can be instantiated with

```
std::integral_constant<int, 42> i;
std::integral_constant<bool, true> b;
std::integral_constant<float, 3.14> f;
...
```

and each of those instances can be used just like the value they contains, i.e.: can be passed around, used in math operations, comparisons, etc.

But i cannot understand why should i use those structs instead of the actual contained values, nor if i can actually access the value type (i.e.: `int`, `bool` and `float`) at runtime to do stuff with it.

Can someone present a simple example of practical use of this feature? An example that explain its usage difference from using the actual values?

Comment: The difference is that `std::integral_constant<int, 42>` is a type and `42` is a value. It's many times easier to deal with a type then a value in you template code. Additionally it has `value_type` and `type` and con convert to a conpile time constant of the value when needed.

Comment: It was added in C++11 not 20?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`std::integral_constant` is mainly used as a utility type for writing meta-programming traits, particularly by encoding a type with a type *and a value*. By letting a custom trait inherit from specializations of `std::integral_constant` we get easy, idiomatic access to a stored non-type template parameter through the static member constant `value`, as well as e.g. the value type of this constant via the member typedef `value_type`.

---

#### Examples

`std::integral_constant` could be used for, say, writing a dimensionality trait for a matrix type

```
using index_t = int;
template <index_t M, index_t N, typename S> struct mat {
  // matrix implementation
};
```

as

```
#include <type_traits>

// Default dimensionality 0.
template <class T, typename = void>
struct dimensionality : std::integral_constant<index_t, 0> {};

template <typename S>
struct dimensionality<S, std::enable_if_t<std::is_arithmetic_v<S>>>
    : std::integral_constant<index_t, 1> {};

template <index_t M, index_t N, typename S>
struct dimensionality<mat<M, N, S>> : std::integral_constant<index_t, M * N> {};

template <class T>
inline constexpr index_t dimensionality_v = dimensionality<T>::value;
```

[**DEMO**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/9fc85126bce998a3).

However, a more common use case is to use the two helper typedefs `std::true_type` and `std::false_type` for the common case where `T` is `bool`.

> ```
> Type        Definition
> ----        ----------
> true_type   std::integral_constant<bool, true>
> false_type  std::integral_constant<bool, false>
> ```

E.g. as

```
#include <type_traits>

struct Foo {};

template <typename T>
struct is_foo : public std::false_type {};

template<>
struct is_foo<Foo> : public std::true_type {};

template<typename T>
constexpr bool is_foo_v = is_foo<T>::value;

static_assert(is_foo_v<Foo>, "");
static_assert(!is_foo_v<int>, "");
```